# Implement callback method in JSF composite component

Tags: jsf-2.2, composite-component

I'd like to implement a "callback" feature in my composite component. This method would be called from the backing component when necessary.

The XHTML part is:

```
<cc:interface componentType="partnerSelComp">
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="com.app.data.Partner"/>            
    <cc:attribute name="callback" method-signature="void notify(java.lang.Long)"/>            
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">                                
        <p:inputText id="code" binding="#{cc.partnerCode}">                     
            <p:ajax event="blur" update="code name msg" listener="#{cc.validate}" />                                                                                                    
        </p:inputText> 
        <p:outputLabel id ="name" binding="#{cc.partnerName}"/>                                             
        <p:message id="msg" for="code"/>                
    </span>
</cc:implementation>
```

The relevant part of backing component is:

```
@FacesComponent("partnerSelComp")
public class PartnerSelComp extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    private InputText partnerCode;    
    private OutputLabel partnerName;        

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    public void validate() {
        ...
        MethodExpression exp = (MethodExpression) getAttributes().get("callback"); 
        ...           
    }
    ...                   
 }
```

Above the `exp` gets null value. How can I get the `callback` attribute, and how can I execute it?

Comment: Can you show how you use the component and the backing bean of the passed method for the callback?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Could you provide the information requested by Alex Fire? An answer would be appreciated even more, of course.

Comment: @KarlRichter: If nothing is passed on, it evaluates to 'null'... All 'normal' behaviour. If something IS passed on, there is a lot of basic debug possible that is not related to the 'title' in any way. Plain JSF composite component attribute passing on/evaluation, nothing 'callback' related.

Answer (score 0):

A solution (Java 1.8) to call a function with no args.

Component:

```
<composite:interface>
 <composite:attribute name="buttonCallback" type="java.util.function.Consumer"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
 <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{cc.attrs.buttonCallback.accept(null)}"/>
<composite:implementation>
```

Usage in view:

```
<mycomp:myCC buttonCallback="#{myBackingBean.myCallback}"/>
```

Usage in backing bean:

```
private Consumer<Void> myCallback;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    myCallback= this::myFunction;
}

public void myFunction(Void v) { //... }
```